# Accessing micro service end point from deployed micro service using Kubernetes orchestration

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to deploy my sample micro service Docker image in Kubernetes cluster having 2 node. I explored everything about Pods, Services, Deployment, StatefulSets and Daemon-sets etc.

I am trying to create a sample deployment and Service for that. Here I explored about how deployment provides the scalability and load balancing functionality. And exploring about service discovery by providing Services ClusterIp.

I have two questions:

My scenario is that I am trying to deploy microservice on my on-premise Ubuntu machine. The machine has the IP address of 192.168.1.15. When I am referring Kubernetes, service will also have one clusterIP.

1. If my microservice end point is `/api/v1/loadCustomer`, how I can call this end point? Do I need to use clusterIP also ? Can I call simply 192.168.1.15:8080/api/v1/loadCustomers ?
2. What is the role of clusterIP when I am calling my end point ? Can I directly use port?

I am referring to the following link for exploration:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr:**

you can not access the application using the **clusterIP** from the outside of the cluster. you can access the application using either loadbalancer's IP (`type=LoadBalaner`) or Node's IP (`type=NodePort`).

**benefit of clusterIP:**
As you know that pods can be created and terminated during its life-cycle consequently IP (endpoint IP)address created and terminated.Therefore, clusterIP is static which does not depends of the life-cycle of the pods.

**Long Answer**

**In a Kubernetes cluster**
an application or pod has following abstraction.

**Endpoint IP and Port**:It is provided by the CNI Plugins such as flannel, calico.

- Each pod has an IP and tragetPort which is *UNIQUE*.

you can list and watch the endpoints by the following commands.

```
kubectl get endpoints --all-namespaces
```

**clusterIP and port** :  It is provided by the ***kube-proxy*** component.

- The replicated pods share a clusterIP and Port.
- Load-balancing of request to the replicated pods.
- internally expose so that other pod can discover it

you can list and watch clusterIP and port with the following command

```
kubectl get services --all-namespaces
```

**externalIP and port**: It can be layer 3-4 load balancer's IP and port or node's IP and Nodeport.

if you want to use loadbalancer's IP and port, you can use `type=LoadBalaner` in service file.

If you want to use node's IP, you need to use `type=NodePort` in service file.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. I am exploring about your statements and guidance.I understood the concept of Ips. But I have felt one more doubt here. When I am creating pod am defining port. And also when I am defining the service also adding port. But your statement says that option for node port. I have confusion on that. Did you mean pod port or the service port? Can you clarify that please?

Comment: Hi, when you use `type=NodePort`, you will get a port from the range **default: 30000-32767**. you can check the nodeport by using following command `kubectl get service`. there will be a port from above range. then you can access your appliation with  `http://nodeip:nodeport`

Comment: If you still have questions please let me know, I will try to share my knowledge.

Comment: OK. Great.Got the concept. Thank you Mr. Suresh Vishnoi.

Comment: that's nice, no worries